# PrestaShop - Update a Product using Web-service and t-sql stored procedures / XML

Tags: web-services, t-sql, post, request, prestashop

I want to update a PrestaShop product using web services from tsql.

I have already the xml variable created in sql.

According to the PrestaShop documentation, I have to:

> [...] Send POST HTTP request with the whole XML as body content [...]

Using Get isn't any problem with oa_mothods from sql, but what is the syntax for POST/PUT any xml variables to Create or Update an existing product?

```
declare @xmlRIA xml

set @xmlRIA = CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop>
    <customer>
        <id></id>
        <id_default_group>3</id_default_group>
        <id_lang>1</id_lang>
        <newsletter_date_add>0000-00-00 00:00:00</newsletter_date_add>
        <ip_registration_newsletter></ip_registration_newsletter>
        <last_passwd_gen>2017-04-29 05:34:22</last_passwd_gen>
        <secure_key></secure_key>
        <deleted>0</deleted>
        <passwd></passwd>
        <lastname>test</lastname>
        <firstname>test</firstname>
        <email>kow@testde.com</email>
        <id_gender>2</id_gender>
        <birthday>0000-00-00</birthday>
        <newsletter>0</newsletter>
        <optin>0</optin>
        <website></website>
        <company></company>
        <siret></siret>
        <ape></ape>
        <outstanding_allow_amount>0.000000</outstanding_allow_amount>
        <show_public_prices>0</show_public_prices>
        <id_risk>0</id_risk>
        <max_payment_days>0</max_payment_days>
        <active>1</active>
        <note></note>
        <is_guest>0</is_guest>
        <id_shop>1</id_shop>
        <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
        <date_add>2017-04-29 11:34:22</date_add>
        <date_upd>2017-04-29 11:34:22</date_upd>
        <reset_password_token></reset_password_token>
        <reset_password_validity>0000-00-00 00:00:00</reset_password_validity>
        <associations>
            <groups>
                <group>
                    <id>3</id>
                </group>
            </groups>
        </associations>
    </customer>
</prestashop>
 'as XML)






-- Open a connection
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed' goto final end

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OACreate open' goto final end

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OACreate Authentication failed' goto final end

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OACreate Content-type failed' goto final end

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, '';
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OAMethod send failed' goto final end

-- Handle response
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OAGetProperty status' goto final end

EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
if @ret <> 0 begin set @MessageError = 'sp_OAGetProperty statusText failed' goto final end


EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @xmlria
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('sp_OAMethod SEND 2 failed.', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updating an existing Product using PrestaShop Web-service**

This assumes your XML is stored in a SimpleXML object (in PHP) and the existing Product ID is 1.

```
<?php

include(__DIR__.'/config/config.inc.php');
include(__DIR__.'/init.php');
include(__DIR__.'/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

/* Connect to the PrestaShop Web-service */
define('PS_SHOP_URL', 'http://localhost/prestashop');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'YOURWSKEY');
$ws = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_URL, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, false);

$result = $ws->edit(['resource' => 'products', 'id' => 1, 'putXml' => $xml->asXML()]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**More examples and links**

You can find the PrestaShop web-service documentation here:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/webservice/

You can find the library here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/PSWebServiceLibrary.php

You can find more examples (retrieve, add, update, delete, etc.) here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/tree/master/examples

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is ok from php, but my question was about consuming prestashop webservices from T-SQL

Comment: In PHP, you can connect to T-SQL using PDO and then use the code above, it will work ;-)